# WTForms submitting form twice when multiple forms are in the same page

Tags: javascript, python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

On my view I have a few different forms.  In one you enter a first and last name to search for.  If there are results, the page refreshes and a second form to pick a user is displayed as a table where clicking on a row submits the data from that row.  For some reason, submitting the second form results in submitting two values for each field: one completely empty and one with the correct information.

I have some javascript that will be executed when a row in a table is clicked.  It's supposed to fill out and submit a hidden form with the data from the table.  The problem I'm running into is that when the form is submitted, two sets of values are submitted.  request.form after the form is submitted contains the following:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('csrf_token', u'1420171907##6ad5346730985191250a52e6432e924ef05c23ee'), ('last_name', u''), ('last_name', u'Smith'), ('first_name', u''), ('first_name', u'John')])
```

Here's the script:

```
$('table#theTable tr').click(function () {
var cells = this.getElementsByTagName('td');
$('#selectuser_last_name').val(cells[0].innerHTML);
$('#selectuser_first_name').val(cells[1].innerHTML);
document.selectuser.submit();
});
```

and here is the HTML to go along with it:

```
<table id="theTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Last</th>
            <th>First</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for user in users %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ user.last_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.first_name }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
<form id=selectUserForm action="/handle_users" method="post" name="selectuser">
    {{ forms.selectuser.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ forms.selectuser.last_name(id="selectuser_last_name") }}
    {{ forms.selectuser.first_name(id="selectuser_first_name") }}
    <input type="submit">Test</input>
</form>
```

I'm using Python and Flask to handle whatever is posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're actually submitting twice- once before there's anything in the form, and once after it's populated (the latter by the javascript, the former via the form submit mechanism).

If the user isn't really inputting anything into the form, but this is a simple call to the server any time a row is clicked. Skip the whole form, it's not helping here. Just pass a call to the server with the info you need- can be a simple ajax post:

```
 $('table#theTable tr').click(function () {
   var cells = this.getElementsByTagName('td');
   $.ajax({ 
        type : "POST",
        url : "/handle_users",
        async:true,
        contentType : 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({first_name:cells[0].innerHTML,last_name:cells[1].innerHTML}, null, '\t'),
        success : function(data) {
            // optional: do something when server-side processing is done 
        }
    });
});
```

Then Grab your data on from flask using `request.get_json()` in the /handle_users route.

Comment: Nice! But how do you go about validation?  WTForms makes that easy.

Comment: @PearSquirrel, please accept the answer if it resolves the question as you posed it. More to the point, if there's no user input, just a click on a row, check your data within the table. For example, you can conditionally color your valid and invalid rows differently, and make invalid rows inactive ('un-clickable'). There are numerous jquery table plugins to do more sophisticated work with tables, ajax, jquery, etc. i used DataTables (see DataTables.net) with success.